# JSP - Display Image Issue

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am using code **< img src="C:/NetBeanProject/images.jpg" alt="abc" width="42" height="42"/>** to display an image to my jsp page. However, the image is not shown in the page. Is there any wrong with that code ?

Comment: Verify the name of image file and name and path at <img/> tag.

Comment: which code..?post atleast that code portion that you are trying to display image.

Comment: I have verified many times the path and file name.

Comment: @Tijo, the bold letter code is which I use to display image.

Comment: Create a folder under root (say images) of web-app, copy that file in it and use relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web-app, images and public resources must be located at folder under the root. You should have to create folder `"images"` under `"web"` (netbeans project) and move `images.jpg` in `images` folder.

```
web/
   |___/images
   |      images.jpg
   |
   | index.jsp
```

In index.jsp,

```
<img src="images/images.jpg" alt="logo"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

avoid the space inside img tag before `img` like `<img src="C:/NetBeanProject/images.jpg" alt="abc" width="42" height="42"/>`.

It will work.

There was some space is space is showing in your code inside `img` tag.